# Where does nginx store the rewrite_log?

Tags: testing, logging, url-rewriting, nginx

When you turn on the nginx rewrite log with `rewrite_log on;`, where does the system actually log that info? It doesn't seem to be in the documentation, and a decent search through google doesn't turn anything up.

I have also tried enabling and looking in both the access and error logs. No luck.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If `rewrite_log on;` is used then the rewrite information will be logged to `error_log` at `notice` level. There is no separate log file.

Comment: to log rewrites at a specific level you can specify the level by defining: `error_log logs/error.log info`

Answer (score 15):

by default turning `"rewrite_log on;"` affects only if your config file `"error_log logs/error.log notice;"` already marks which non-default event levels do you need to be logged.

> "Setting a certain log level will cause all messages of the specified
> and more severe log levels to be logged."

So, first `"error_log logs/error.log notice;"` then `"rewrite_log on;"` and error.log starts receiving rewriting logging

http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite